# how can I remove specific array entry in my mongodb/mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My `mongoose` model looks similar to:

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    my_username: {type: String},
    blocked_users: [{
        my_username: {type: String, required: true},
        display_name: {type: String, required: true}
    }],
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

now, I created endpoint for adding new blocked_users to this array. It looks as follows:

```
usersRoutes.post('/:username/blockedUsers/add', function(req, res){
    var username = req.params.username;
    var blockedUser = req.body.blockedUser;

    if (blockedUser != undefined) {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            username,
            {
                $push: {"blocked_users": blockedUser},
            },
            {safe: true, upsert: true, new: true},
            function(err, user) {
                if(err)
                    console.log(err);

                res.json(user);
            }
        );
    }
});
```

and that works nice. But how can I remove the specific user from that list?
Is there a way of removing him from that list by passing only `my_username` and not the whole `blockedUser` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {
    $pop: {"blocked_users": blockedUser._id}  
}, function (err, user) {
    // handle callback
});
```

`blockedUser` is the user you want to remove from the list